# Really odd pattern: $\sqrt{1+(s(x))^2} $ $= f(x) - g(x)$, where $f(x)+g(x)=s(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

$ \sqrt{1+(s(x))^2} =$ $\sqrt{1+(f(x)+g(x))^2} $ $= f(x) - g(x)$, where $s(x) = f(x) + g(x) $

Is there any explanation for this pattern? I found it completely by accident without doing any algebra, but is there an algebraic proof? I have yet to find a situation where it does not hold, but I haven't tested out a huge variety of situations. I've tried algebrically proving the general case my self but to no avail.

If it's relevant, I discovered this while solving problems revolving around arc length and arc length functions using integrals (this involves an equation in which the items of the above equation appear).

A couple examples of where it does work:

$f(x)=x^2$ and $ g(x) = \frac{1}{4}x^2$

$f(x) = 2x$ and $g(x)= \frac{1}{8}x$

$f(x)=x^{\frac{3}{2}}/3$ and $g(x) = x^{\frac{1}{2}}$

$f(x) =1/4x^2$ and $g(x) = (lnx)/2$

$f(x) = e^x/4$ and $g(x) = e^{-x}$

Maybe there's a specific pattern on the things it works on that I'm not seeing?

Just found this really strange and wanting to know whether there is some algebra behind it. Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: What makes you think it's true? (it's not, in fact)

Comment: Are you sure this holds? What if $f(x)=g(x)=0$?

Comment: It holds when $f(x) g(x) =-1/4$ and $f-g$ is nonnegative.

Comment: @MattSamuel, wow, that does seem to be the criteria of some of the situations (and possibly all of them, can't tell if it works with my last two examples) where it holds! How did you figure that out?!

Comment: @James Square both sides. Stuff cancels, and you can solve for $f(x) g(x) $.

Comment: @MattSamuel though, if you look at my third example, $f(x)g(x) = x^2/3$. Yet those two functions still satisfy the rule...so maybe there's more to this? Also, I tried squaring both sides and solving but I couldn't get that, I think that's just me though.

Comment: They don't satisfy the rule except at values where the product is $-1/4$. I gave an exact characterization. Your examples that don't satisfy it are wrong.

Comment: @Matt Samuel you can simplify your nonnegative difference rule because $f$ and $g$ with a negative product are forced to have opposite signs.  Thus $f(x)g(x)=-1/4\text{ and }f(x)>0$.